# Help with page nav?

Tags: php, navigation

I am taking over a site and we are making a sister site to it, but the problem is that the navigation was set up for the other site - so I'm having an issue getting the navigation to link to the pages. What it is doing is using a filter of some sort... so when I try to click a link on the nav bar nothing happens but an empty drop down menu displays. We have no need for child pages on this project so I need help figuring out how to edit the filter so that parent pages act as links rather than "menu titles" if you will.

here's my code:

```
<?php 

                //add_filter ('wp_list_pages', 'formatNavList');
                $myPages = wp_list_pages(array('title_li' =>'', 'depth' =>1, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' =>0, )); 

                $templateDir = get_bloginfo("template_directory");
                $pattern1 = "/<li.*?>.*?<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/is";
                $replString1 = "<li class='navButton' >$1
                <div class='dropdown1Col' >
                    <img class='dropdown1ColTop' src='$templateDir/images/bgGraphics/DropDownNav_1ColTop_200x30.png'  />
                    <div>
                        <img class='dropdown1ColMid' src='$templateDir/images/bgGraphics/DropDownNav_1ColMid_Stretch.png' />";

                $pattern2 = "/(<\/li>\s*?<li[^>]*navButton.*?>)/is";
                $replString2 = "            <p class='clearFloat' />
                                    </div>
                                <img class='dropdown1ColBtm' src='$templateDir/images/bgGraphics/DropDownNav_1ColBtm_200x30.png'  />
                            </div>$1";


                $pattern3 = "/(<\/li>\s*?)$/is";
                $replString3 = "            <p class='clearFloat' />
                                    </div>
                                <img class='dropdown1ColBtm' src='$templateDir/images/bgGraphics/DropDownNav_1ColBtm_200x30.png'  />
                            </div>";

                $menu = explode('<li ', $myPages);
                $sub = 0;
                $i = 0;
                $id = array();

                foreach ($menu as $key => $val) {

                    $match = $matches = 0;

                    if ($sub == 0){
                        $id[] = $key;
                        $pos = strpos($val,'<a');
                        $text = preg_replace($pattern1, $replString1, "<li alt='$sub' $val");
                        $output .= $text;
                    }else{
                        $output .= "<li alt='$sub' $val";
                    }
                    if (preg_match_all("/(<ul class='children'>)/",$val,$match,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)){
                        $sub = $sub + count($match[0]);
                    }else if (preg_match_all("/(<\/ul>)/",$val,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)){
                        $sub = $sub - count($matches[0]);
                    };
                    $i++;
                    if($i==3){$i=0;};

                }
                $output = preg_replace($pattern2, $replString2, $output);
                $output = preg_replace($pattern3, $replString3, $output);

                echo $output;
            ?>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the WP_Nav Menu for your site. To use this feature, just add this in place of your current nav:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'primary-menu' => __( 'Main Menu' ),
        'secondary-menu' => __( 'Secondary Menu' ),
        'tertiary-menu' => __( 'Tertiary Menu' )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Then you can use this to display the navigation in your template files:

```
<div id="menu">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?><!-- End Navigation -->
</div><!-- End #menu-->
```

With the code above you can use up to 3 menu's in different locations. To add another, just change the 'primary-menu' in the example above to one of the other 3 listed in the functions.php file. You can now go to the WP-Admin>Appearance>Menu's and create your nav menu and add the pages/posts, or categories/tags to the menu and make it as many levels deep as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with using a page menu (though I would strongly recommend @Jeremy Jared's solution of using custom Nav Menus), replace all of your above code with this:

```
wp_list_pages( array( 'title_li' =>'', 'depth' =>1, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title' ) );
```

Then, use CSS to apply whatever layout/style you need.